# Weak derivative of the Weierstrass function?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The Weierstrass function is a function that is continuous everywhere but nowhere differentiable.
I'm wondering if it has 1-th weak derivative.

According to a book I'm reading, $u(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1) + f(x_2)$ defined in $\Omega = (0,1) \times (0,1)$, where $f$ is the Weierstrass function, actually has 2-th weak derivative. We have
$$0 = \int_\Omega(f(x_1)+f(x_2))\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}dx
_1dx_2$$ for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty (\Omega)$.
Hence weak derivative $D_{x_1}D_{x_2}u = 0.$

So does weak derivate $D_{x_1}u$ exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a point of terminology: as discussed in [Are weak derivatives and distributional derivatives different?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451746/are-weak-derivatives-and-distributional-derivatives-different?rq=1) a "weak derivative" of $f$ is understood to be a locally integrable function $g$ such that 
$$
\int_\Omega f\phi' = -\int_\Omega g\phi\quad \forall \phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega).
$$
This property implies that:

1. $f$ is an absolutely continuous representative: [Absolutely continuous representative of Sobolev function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491410/absolutely-continuous-representative-of-sobolev-function)
2. $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere (as a consequence of 1, see [Proof that absolute continuity implies differentiability a.e.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512173/proof-that-absolute-continuity-implies-differentiability-a-e)

The Weierstrass function is nowhere differentiable, and therefore does not have a weak derivative.

As an exercise, you can try to streamline the above argument 1-2 by proving directly that a continuous function $f$ with weak derivative $g$ is differentiable at every Lebesgue point of $g$.

If you asked about *distributional* derivative, the answer would be yes.
Every continuous function is locally integrable, therefore is a distribution, and therefore has a distributional derivative.

Comment: So a continuous function with weak derivatives is supposed to be absolutely continuous? I don't know if I get that right.

Comment: Yes that is correct. The converse is also true, absolutely continuous functions are weakly differentiable.